# Duplicate A Marker Icon in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this cide to duplicate an icon from a previously declared marker, but it does not work:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom:12,
  center:latlng2,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map:map,
  icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://www.gettyicons.com/free-icons/108/gis-gps/png/24/needle_left_yellow_2_24.png',
    new google.maps.Size(24, 24),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 24)
  )
});

var babyIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker.getIcon(),
  new google.maps.Size(
      marker.getIcon().size.width * this.iconScale_,
      marker.getIcon().size.height * this.iconScale_
  ),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point (
      marker.getIcon().anchor.x * this.iconScale_,
      marker.getIcon().anchor.y * this.iconScale_ / 2
  )
);

// kill the shadow
babyIcon.shadow = null;

this.babyMarker_ = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
  icon: babyIcon,
  draggable:false,
  map:map
});
```

it does not work, the icon does not display and all that. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the url of the MarkerImage, the property you need is .ra (don't ask me)

```
var babyIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  marker.getIcon().ra,
  new google.maps.Size(
      marker.getIcon().size.width * this.iconScale_,
      marker.getIcon().size.height * this.iconScale_
  ),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point (
      marker.getIcon().anchor.x * this.iconScale_,
      marker.getIcon().anchor.y * this.iconScale_ / 2
  )
);
```

Comment: Also latitude longitude 0,0 is in the ocean just below Africa on the equator.

Comment: can't quite get the origin parameter for the marker image. I am converting the code from v2 and it used the Icon object. It had anchor and size properties but no origin. What can I set for the origin anyway? the (0,0) I gave it were from the maps example in the documentation

Comment: According to the Chrome javascript debugger, .d is the origin, .b is the resize parameter.